# How to check if a div has ANY background values?

Tags: javascript, css, background

So I wanna check if a div has any background values instead of checking each value like:

```
if (item.style.background === "" && item.style.backgroundColor === "" etc.
```

Is there any way to do it? My main goal is to set a white background color if the div/item doesn't have any background.

Comment: Using `element.style` only checks *inline* style and not computed style. Does that apply to your use case? Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few choices, but first: It depends on whether you only care about **inline** styles, or you also care about styles applied via CSS.

In the below, I've used the `style` property on the element, which **only** has the inline styles. If you want styles from CSS instead, use `getComputedStyle` on the element and use the resulting object instead of the `style` property in the below. (If you need to support seriously old versions of IE, they don't have `getComputedStyle`, but they have a `currentStyle` property on the element that does much the same thing.)

To the choices:

1. Just list the style names you're interested in as an array (there aren't that many) and use `every` or `some`:

```
var keys = [
  "background", "backgroundColor", "backgroundUrl" // ...
];
if (!keys.some(k => Boolean(div.style[k]))) {
    console.log("Add the white background");
} else {
    console.log("Don't add it");
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function check(div) {
  var keys = [
    "background", "backgroundColor", "backgroundUrl" // ...
  ];
  if (!keys.some(k => Boolean(div.style[k]))) {
      console.log(div.id + ": Add the white background");
  } else {
      console.log(div.id + ": Don't add it");
  }
}
check(document.getElementById("example1"));
check(document.getElementById("example2"));
```

```html
<div id="example1" style="color: blue"></div>
<div id="example2" style="background-color: blue"></div>
```

2. In modern browsers, `div.style` is iterable (the iterator returns the names of the styles that are set, for instance `"background-color"`), so:

```
if (![...div.style].some(k => k.startsWith("background") && Boolean(div.style[k]))) {
    console.log(div.id + ": Add the white background");
} else {
    console.log(div.id + ": Don't add it");
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function check(div) {
  if (![...div.style].some(k => k.startsWith("background") && Boolean(div.style[k]))) {
      console.log(div.id + ": Add the white background");
  } else {
      console.log(div.id + ": Don't add it");
  }
}
check(document.getElementById("example1"));
check(document.getElementById("example2"));
```

```html
<div id="example1" style="color: blue"></div>
<div id="example2" style="background-color: blue"></div>
```

(Or avoid the interator by using `Array.prototype.some.call(div.style, k => ...`.)

3. Even in old browsers, it has a `length` property and an `item` method that gives you the name for each style property:

```
var flag = true;
var style = div.style;
for (var i = 0; flag && i < style.length; ++i) {
  var k = style.item(i);
  if (k.indexOf("background") === 0 && Boolean(div.style[k])) {
    flag = false;
  }
}
if (flag) {
  console.log(div.id + ": Add the white background");
} else {
  console.log(div.id + ": Don't add it");
}
```

```js
function check(div) {
  var flag = true;
  var style = div.style;
  for (var i = 0; flag && i < style.length; ++i) {
    var k = style.item(i);
    if (k.indexOf("background") === 0 && Boolean(div.style[k])) {
      flag = false;
    }
  }
  if (flag) {
    console.log(div.id + ": Add the white background");
  } else {
    console.log(div.id + ": Don't add it");
  }
}
check(document.getElementById("example1"));
check(document.getElementById("example2"));
```

```html
<div id="example1" style="color: blue"></div>
<div id="example2" style="background-color: blue"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

welcome to StackOverflow!

You can use the `hasOwnProperty()` method to check if there's a background or background-color property.

You do it like this:

```js
if (!item.style.hasOwnProperty('background')&& !item.style.hasOwnProperty('backgroundColor'){
    item.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work cross-browser, on many browsers (including Chrome), the property isn't an "own" property, it's an accessor on the prototype.

Comment: According to MDN all browsers support `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty#Browser_compatibility)). So It definitely does work cross-browser. Even back in 2014, its use is already recommended by Matthew Gertner and JavaScript Garden. According to them "Using hasOwnProperty is the only reliable method to check for the existence of a property on an object.".

Comment: The issue isn't hasOwnProperty, the issue is what I said in my comment: *"the property isn't an "own" property, it's an accessor on the prototype."* It's not like it's hard to check. :-) Run [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/bq3r2uhm/) in Firefox. Both the div with a background color and the div w/o one say they don't have it (but if you access it, it's there: `""` or `"blue"` depending). On Chrome, it's the opposite: The property is *always* an own prop, so again the check fails the other way. (I misremembered, should have said Firefox rather than Chrome in my original comment.)